# how to override the paint method without stopping its functionality

Tags: java, graphics, paint, drawstring

So my assignment wants me to create an applet but as an extra I'm supposed to use the paint method to draw a string, for example:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g){
           g.drawString("name, name name", 400,100);
    }
```

My problem is that this pretty much prevents the rest of my app from painting.

Comment: Just place it with the rest of the paint instructions.

Comment: Call `super.paint`, but the next question is, why are you using `paint` and not `paintComponent`?

Comment: Sorry MadProgrammer, this is the first time I've ever even heard of paint or worked with graphics. Thank you though, that did work.

Comment: Then you might like to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)